# Reading .Net Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

This question came just out of curiosity to know our friend the **Stack Trace** a little better.

As a C# (.NET) developer every one must have seen a yellow stack trace like the one below.

[image]

Most of the things in it are easily understood like the message `Attempt to divide by zero` and the method where it occur `Page_Load` even the path of the .cs file also. But after 3 years of experience the thing I still don't know is what those numbers with + sign at the end of methods denote in here, like `+51`, `+92`, `+54` and `+772`.

Does anybody know what these are?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is offset of instruction (not IL but native) that caused the exception.

Read more at http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/24/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx